# Recursive Self Referencing JSON-Schema

Tags: jsonschema

Is it a valid json schema:

```
  object:
    $ref: '#/definitions/object'
```

Would you recommend to use such format?

Answer (score 19):

Self references are allowed and useful.  However, your example looks like it would just be a referential infinite loop.  Here is an example of a JSON Schema that uses recursive references to define a tree structure of unlimited depth.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "tree": { "$ref": "#/definitions/tree" }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "tree": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "value": { "type": "string" },
        "branches": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/tree" },
          "minItems": 1
        }
      },
      "required": ["value"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify a maxDepth for the recursion?

Comment: Nope. There is no way in JSON Schema to know what depth you are at, so there is no way to limit at some depth.

Comment: Is it that this approach only works with "properties" but fails with "patternProperties"? I get `Unresolvable JSON pointer: 'definitions/tree'` if wrapped with `patternProperties" and uses a RegEx key like "^.*$". @JasonDesrosiers

Comment: There's no reason why this wouldn't work with `patternProperties` or any other applicator. There's either some subtle error in your schema, or the validator you're using has a bug.